# vscodeで行の途中から改行するキーボードショートカットを教えてください

Tags: vscode

vscodeで行の途中から改行するキーボードショートカットを教えてください

vim で言うところの `o` です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この辺ではだめでしょうか?

> Ctrl-Enter  editor.action.insertLineAfter   (現在行の次に行を追加)
>   Ctrl-Shift-Enter  editor.action.insertLineBefore  (現在行の前に行を追加)

後は、Vim用の拡張を入れるとか。